# Localize app's name in android but deploy two apps in device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, localized

**Main Activity.cs**

```
 [Activity(Theme = "@style/MainTheme",Label = "@string/app_name" ,MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation , ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

**Values-zh/Strings.xml**

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">斯瓦扬布大佛塔</string>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionCode="21" android:versionName="1.0.12" 
          android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:label="Swayambhu" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</manifest>
```

Localized values directory was created as follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization#stringsxml-file-format) but two apps deploy in device. one with localize app's name and another app's name was follow application name in android manifest.

Comment: Make sure that you didn't change the package name  of the Android project. And you could share a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't change the package name. And I had share more code here.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue . You could follow the steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization#resource-folders .If the issue still exists , you could share a sample .